# Mock Spring service in controller test using Spock

Tags: spring-boot, spock, spring-test

I am looking for a way to mock a Service bean used in Controller so I can test only controller using MockMvc. But I can't find an easy way to replace real bean with Spock mock. Everything uses spring-boot 1.3.2 version. More details below:

I have a following controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/issues")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class NewsletterIssueController {

  private final GetLatestNewsletterIssueService latestNewsletterIssueService;

  @RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    path = "/latest"
  )
  public ResponseEntity getLatestIssue() {
    Optional<NewsletterIssueDto> latestIssue = latestNewsletterIssueService.getLatestIssue();

    if (latestIssue.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(latestIssue.get());
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
  }
}
```

And Integration Spock test for this class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Application], loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class NewsletterIssueControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  MockMvc mockMvc

  @Autowired
  GetLatestNewsletterIssueService getLatestNewsletterIssueService

  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

  def setup() {
    ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder mockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
    mockMvc = mockMvcBuilder.build()
  }

  def "Should get 404 when latest issue does not exist"() {
    given:
        getLatestNewsletterIssueService.getLatestIssue() >> Optional.empty() // this won't work because it is real bean, not a Mock
    expect:
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/issues/latest")
                .contentType(JVM_BLOGGERS_V1)
                .accept(JVM_BLOGGERS_V1)
        ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNotFound())
  }

}
```

I need a way to replace this autowired bean with a Mock/Stub so I can define interactions in 'given' section.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a local configuration in the test and override the bean there.

I don't know Groovy, but it would like this in Java:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = NewsletterIssueControllerIntegrationSpec.Conf.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class NewsletterIssueControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
  @Configuration
  @Import(Application.class)
  public static class Conf {
    @Bean
    public GetLatestNewsletterIssueService getLatestNewsletterIssueService() {
      return mock(GetLatestNewsletterIssueService.class);
    }
  }

  // […]
}
```

Caveat: This approach works well with Mockito, but you might need a pre-release version of Spock for it to work, ref: https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/546

By the way: Spring Boot 1.4 will provide a `@MockBean` construction to simplify this.

Comment: This one would solve my problem if I was using Java, hence +1, bur for Spock it is not so simple as you noticed. I need either new Spring Boot or new Spock to make it work the way I planned.

Answer (score 0):

With Spock 1.2 you can use SpringBean annotation to inject mocked service in spring context https://objectpartners.com/2018/06/14/spock-1-2-annotations-for-spring-integration-testing/

So with this new annotation your test would be :

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [NewsletterIssueController], secure = false)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class NewsletterIssueControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc

  @SpringBean
  GetLatestNewsletterIssueService getLatestNewsletterIssueService


  def setup() {
      // nothing to do as SpringBean and WebMvcTest do the job for you
  }

  def "Should get 404 when latest issue does not exist"() {
    given:
        getLatestNewsletterIssueService.getLatestIssue() >> Optional.empty() // this won't work because it is real bean, not a Mock
    expect:
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/issues/latest")
                .contentType(JVM_BLOGGERS_V1)
                .accept(JVM_BLOGGERS_V1)
        ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNotFound())
  }

}
```

Comment: Vincent, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I put more details in my answer. Thanks for your feedback.